# move balls in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

i'm trying to make my balls move in this canvas but every time i got something else
i got creating a new balls like i'm refreshing the page
so can any one tell me how to move this balls

```js
var windowElenemt = document.getElementById("window");
var ctx = windowElenemt.getContext('2d');
var vx = 9;
var vy = 9;


  function draw(){
    var ballsColors = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    var boxY = Math.floor(Math.random()*600);
    var boxX = Math.floor(Math.random()*1360);
    var ballPlace = Math.floor((Math.random()*30)+5);

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,windowElenemt.width,windowElenemt.height);

    boxX+=vx;
    boxY+=vy;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(boxX,boxY,ballPlace,0,2*Math.PI,false);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#" + ballsColors;
    ctx.fill();
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
    setInterval(draw(),1000);



  for(i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++){
   draw();
 }
```

```html
<body onload="draw()">
<canvas id="window" width= '1364' height='623' style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;" display:'block;'></canvas>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your `boxX` and `boxY` variables are declared to have a random number. i see you call the `draw()` function multiple times. i think its probably that each time your `draw()` function executes it re-declares the `boxX` and `boxY` values. try declaring them outside the `draw()` function like this

```
var windowElenemt = document.getElementById("window");
var ctx = windowElenemt.getContext('2d');
var vx = 0.1;
var vy = 0.1;
var boxY = Math.floor(Math.random()*600);
    var boxX = Math.floor(Math.random()*1360);
    var ballPlace = Math.floor((Math.random()*30)+5);
   //var ballsColors = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    

  function draw(){
  
 boxX+=vx;
    boxY+=vy;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,windowElenemt.width,windowElenemt.height);

    
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(boxX,boxY,ballPlace,0,2*Math.PI,false);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.fill();
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
    setInterval(draw(),1000);



  for(i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++){
   draw();
 }
```

i changed the vx and vy to 0.1 because it would leave the screen too fast and you wont be able to see it. if you turn off the `ctx.clearrect` part you can see exactly how it moved because it wont be clearing it anymore.